# Can not found EasyPermissions library error when run application?

Tags: android, android-library

I am using EasyPermissions library in my project . It build successfully but got error at the run time. I am building my application in 28. I use the latest version and before that  but still getting the same error.

Comment: can you add your code and debug log

Comment: I am using dependency implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.0'  and at run time i got this  error: cannot access EasyPermissions
class file for pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions not found

Comment: when i build compile instead of implementation then it working fine.

Comment: great , if you want other options check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I recommended to use below Android Run time Permission Library

implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'

First declare your permissions in the manifest.

like

Sample code:
1) Single Permission ()

```
Permissions.check(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, null, new PermissionHandler() {
@Override
public void onGranted() {
    // do your task.
}
});
```

2)Multiple permissions:

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, 
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

   Permissions.check(this/*context*/, permissions, null/*rationale*/, null/*options*/, 
new PermissionHandler() {
@Override
public void onGranted() {
    // do your task.
}
});
```

3)Customized permissions request:

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
String rationale = "Please provide location permission so that you can ...";
    Permissions.Options options = new Permissions.Options()
    .setRationaleDialogTitle("Info")
    .setSettingsDialogTitle("Warning");

Permissions.check(this/*context*/, permissions, rationale, options, new 
PermissionHandler() {
@Override
public void onGranted() {
    // do your task.
}

@Override
public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
    // permission denied, block the feature.
}
});
```

> Check this library: @github https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

**or check this answer for permission code**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55452495/10758304